# Precompiling assets fails on Heroku deploy but works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass

I recently started trying to clean up some css within a heroku app and ran into some trouble when I tried to start using SCSS style variables. My approach was essentially to create a theme.css.scss file which held all the colors and then use those in my other modules. For the purpose of explaining this, I'll call it bracket.css.scss

Now I've debugged this by paring things down as much as I can, and the issue appears to be that heroku is for some reason trying to compile the bracket file without the variables set in theme. I've hacked away everything so that I have the following:

**application.css.scss**

```
 /*
 *= require_self
 */

 @import "theme.css.scss";
 @import "bracket.css.scss";
```

**theme.css.scss**

```
$primary-red: #BC1414;
$faded-red: #3B1B1B;
$dark-red: #8a0f0f;
```

**bracket.css.scss**

```
.Bracket li {
  color: $primary-red;
}
```

Now locally, this all compiles fine by running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets`, but for some reason, heroku is trying to compile the file bare. Even if I remove bracket.css.scss from the import statements and leave it in the directory, it still tries to compile it and still gives the error:

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-03-04T01:26:27.759654 #541]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9a38718ecc0e6f745aaabdf36773113f/public/assets/application-06ee955f8c010c7ce7ddac90c464ee2b.js
```

remote:        rake aborted!
    Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$primary-red".
    remote:        (in /tmp/build_fc4a2b49d91462a9a653dc2e95ed1439/app/assets/stylesheets/bracket.css.scss:6)

(side-note: I do have 'rails_12factor' gem installed in production)

I've even tried altering production.rb and overriding the precompile list to `config.assets.precompile = ["application.js", "application.css"]`

I've worked around this for the moment by precompiling locally and committing, but this isn't my preferred approach. It seems like heroku is just compiling everything in the tree individually instead of reading application.css. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some way to prevent Heroku from going wild with its precompiling?

Comment: Are you sure on heroku the exact same command is being run: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets`. Do you have a heroku log you can check to make sure this is true? Or a heroku log that says what command is being executed that results in that `Sass::SyntaxError` being returned? Heroku doesn't do any asset precompiling all on it's own, _some_ rake task or other command is being executed on your app, but you didn't include the log showing what one. The answer is probably there.

Comment: Or wait, does this occur when you deploy the app to heroku, or does it occur when you access the app which seems to have been succesfully deployed at first?

Comment: On deploy to heroku, I'll expand the text a little bit but it's in the precompile phase. It does the js fine then errors out. As for @jrochkind question..it just says assets:precompile. I believe it actually does run the rake task, but I don't know how to find the specifics if there are any weird options that would affect it

Comment: oh wait, and I just remembered the first face-palm gotcha to check: Do you have any uncommitted changes or files in your local copy, where the asset precompile works? Do a `git status` and make sure it's entirely clean. If your local copy isn't exaclty what's in git -- then heroku isn't executing the same source you are when you try to reproduce locally! I have had issues like this that were the result of me forgetting to add a file entirely to git or something like that, that took me an hour to figure out, then I felt like a moron, heh.

Comment: Yup, clean as a whistle! Again, my hunch is that it's trying to compile more for some reason. It probably does have to do with some caching or the command being different in a way I haven't reproed or something. FWIW, running the command I listed above on heroku after compiling the assets seems to work?

Comment: Hm. Add what version of Rails too. All heroku can do is run commands present in your source (ie, in Rails), it doesn't have any independent asset precompilation abilities. I think there's nothing heroku could be doing that you couldn't reproduce locally if you did the same thing from the same source -- the trick is figuring out exactly what heroku is actually doing. I'm kind of stumped too. We must both be missing something, hopefully someone else will come along!

Comment: and one more potentially stupid suggestion -- make sure you do NOT have ./tmp/cache checked into git.

Comment: Yeah definitely don't...tried removing it locally too. Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2

Answer (score -2):

First locally clean up your assets

```
rake assets:clean
```

Then make pre compiling false for production environment

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

Then compile local assets

```
rake assets:precompile
```

then push on heroku

Comment: Hey Keval! Thanks for the response. In my original question though I mention that I had this approach working already, however I'd prefer not to have to do that step locally as there's a few developers who contribute and push (trying to keep things simple esp git conflicts and push conflicts and stuff).